# In Python/Django, how do I import one service I created from another one I created?

Tags: django, python-3.x, service, import

I'm using Pyton 3.7 and Django.  I have a directory where I keep my services

```
my_project
    my_app
        services
            __init__.py
            foo_service.py
            bar_service.py
```

"**init**.py" is empty.  Within "foo_service.py", I define class "FooService" and within "bar_service.py," I define class "BarService."  How do I import BarService in FooService?  I tried

```
import services.bar_service
```

but got the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'services'
```

Comment: `from .bar_service import BarService`.

Comment: Thanks that was the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either relative or absolute imports:

Relative is that Daniel proposed:

```
from .bar_service import BarService
```

I prefer to use absolute in case you want to move a file or code to another file. [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) also explicitly recommends absolute imports:

```
from my_app.services.bar_service import BarService
```